# How to solve this Pandas and PanelOLS indexing problem

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science

[image]

I have trouble sending my data frame to panelOLS model.
the dataframe didn't using any column as index

then it returns an error massage:
ValueError: Series can only be used with a 2-level MultiIndex

Doeas that mean I need to use double index and use datetime type as my indices?

Comment: Try use suggestion from dupe answer, if still problem let me know.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of a dupe answer. But I think it may not fit my situation.  It suggest to use set_index() to make a secondary index after converting 'year' to datetime. My major concern is to make the 'YEAR_QUARTER' into a 2 level multindex

Comment: yop, try `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.str.replace('_','Q', regex=True))` and then add some column to index with `append=True` - check answer.